# Help me identify this damsel-in-distress tale

Tags: myth-identification, medieval-europe

I remember reading a long time ago about a knight and his wife. It was implied that this was the continuation of many adventures:

After marrying, and with the intention of keeping their love alive like the first day, they both decide to start a journey by land, with a peculiarity: the woman travelled X amount of days ahead of the knight, so she would put herself willingly in a [damsel-in-distress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damsel_in_distress) situation for the knight to arrive and rescue her.

I've tried to identify this story for so many years with no success, I even searched TV tropes (which I'm not gonna link to not ruin your productivity).

At that time I was reading about Arthurian and Germanic medieval legends, so I tend to associate this story with that context, but my memory could be wrong and this could be a false hint. I'm quite sure that this was not a novel or a movie though.

Can you help me identify this myth/legend/tale?

Comment: Was this story a modern adaptation?  (The take on the damsel-in-distress has the feeling of post-modernism.)

Comment: @DukeZhou Not a modern retelling, as far as I know. And yes, it sounds quite (post)modern for its playing with the damsel-in-distress trope, but that's one of the reasons why it caught with me. BTW, that's the only part of the story that I can remember.

Comment: Was it poetry or prose?

Comment: @DukeZhou Back then I was reading Mythology in divulgation books, not originals.

Comment: When we find this story, I hope it ends with the wife having to backtrack and rescue her husband because he got ensnared in something ridiculous and she was tired of waiting for him. :)